# Check if the first block in a Matrix field matches one of an array of types

Tags: templating, craft3, matrix

I need to check if the first block in a Matrix field matches one of an array of types. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
{% if entry.newsArticleContent.one().type in ['fullWidthImage', 'imageGroup'] %}
    yep
{% else %}
    nope
{% endif %}
```

`{{ entry.newsArticleContent.one().type }}` outputs `fullWidthImage`, but the above conditional outputs `nope`.

The following outputs `yep`:

```
{% if 'fullWidthImage' in ['fullWidthImage', 'imageGroup'] %}
    yep
{% else %}
    nope
{% endif %}
```

so I know it's not a problem with the `if` statement or the fact that I'm checking the value against an array.

Is there a reason why the value of `entry.newsArticleContent.one().type` can't be used in this context?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Thought I should mention that I'm looping through all blocks in the Matrix field later on in the same template. Just in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `entry.newsArticleContent.one().type`, what you're getting is an instance of `craft\models\MatrixBlockType` (https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/models/MatrixBlockType.php)

It just happens to have a [`__toString()`](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/models/MatrixBlockType.php#L93-L96) method that will print out the handle when it's requested, but the `if` comparison you're doing is using the entire `MatrixBlockType` instance.

What you're looking for is:

```
{% if entry.newsArticleContent.one().type.handle  in ['fullWidthImage', 'imageGroup'] %}
```